# Remove hyperlink to edit post in edit.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multi-lingual wordpress site with multiple logins. Now administrator can posts for all languages but editor can only edit post of its authorized language only but can view all.

And I need some functionality to disable/enable edit depending upon condition (also from title) for those posts.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ or https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities ?

Comment: I don't want plugin but I have tried all the possibilities found in web

Comment: To edit editor capabilities, the accepted answer describes this in a better way.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/how-can-i-allow-the-editor-role-to-change-theme-settings

Comment: This doesn't do wht I described above